# How to create a hidden <img> in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can you make a simple tag like `<img src="a.gif">` hidden programmatically using JavaScript?

Comment: Can you clearly state what you wanna do?

Comment: <img src="a.gif" style="display:none">

Comment: I  got the answer , Billy Could you please edit it to understandable

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question.  But there are two approaches to making the image invisible...

Pure HTML

```
<img src="a.gif" style="display: none;" />
```

Or...

HTML + Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myImage").style.display = "none";
</script>

<img id="myImage" src="a.gif" />
```

Comment: display: none; is what I needed. Thank you

Comment: what if i want to show the image? should it be .style.display = true; ?

Comment: To show the image it'd be `.style.display = "inline-block"` which would be the default display behavior of an img. All possible display options are described here... https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/

Answer (score 5):

You can hide an image using javascript like this:

```
document.images['imageName'].style.visibility = hidden;
```

If that isn't what you are after, you need to explain yourself more clearly.

Answer (score 4):

How about

`<img style="display: none;" src="a.gif">`

That will disable the display completely, and not leave a placeholder

Answer (score 3):

This question is vague, but if you want to make the image with Javascript. 
It is simple.

```
function loadImages(src) {
  if (document.images) {
    img1 = new Image();
    img1.src = src;
}
loadImages("image.jpg");
```

The image will be requested but until you show it it will never be displayed.
great for pre loading images you expect to be requests but delaying it until the document is loaded.

[Example](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/image/preload.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the style to display=none:

```
<img src="a.gif" style="display:none">
```