# Why do images in a block element not strictly respect height: 0

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Check the following component (live example shown in this snippet https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-mccarthy-r3v93?file=/src/App.tsx):

```
import * as React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [indexOfDiagnosis, setIndex] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setIndex(indexOfDiagnosis + 1)}>click</button>
      <div>
        {[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].map((_, index) => (
          <img
            key={index}
            alt={"asd"}
            src={
              index % 2
                ? "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563630381190-77c336ea545a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1872&q=80"
                : "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"
            }
            width="80%"
            height="80%"
            style={{ height: index !== indexOfDiagnosis ? "0px" : undefined }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It shows a list of images, where all but one have `height: 0` (these are implicitly hidden).

But, when you click the button to iterate through them, further images are shown with a top offset (as if the previous images still take some space). Why is this happening?

NOTE 1:
In devtools the height, padding, border and margin of each "invisible" image is shown as 0.

NOTE 2:
Also by setting the parent div to `display: flex; flex-direction: column` this offset bug does not happen.

Comment: At 2.5k you must know that you're required to put code _here_. :) Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: because the `img`'s are display inline by default. They are actually "replacement" elements and behave a little differently than other elements. set the `img`'s to `display:block;` and your problem goes away

Comment: If this is an answer, post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to Fix** 
Most browser user agents will render `img` as a `display inline-block.` White-space will be added in between `inline` and `inline-block` elements if space exists between the HTML coding brackets.

To solve your problems the quickest way is to set each `img` element to `display` `block`.

Alternatively, here is how to remove space between inline elements: [How do I remove the space between inline/inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements)

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}
.block {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Defualt -->
<p> Default </p>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563630381190-77c336ea545a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1872&q=80"/>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"/>

<!-- Display Block -->
<p> Display Block </p>
<img class="block" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563630381190-77c336ea545a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1872&q=80"/>
<img class="block" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"/>

<!-- No Whitespace -->
<p> No Whitespace </p>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563630381190-77c336ea545a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1872&q=80"/><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494548162494-384bba4ab999?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=80"/>
```

**Additional Suggestions** 
Instead of using the `height: 0;` property to hide an element, might I suggest using `display: none;` instead? This will truly hide it from the DOM. To unhide it from the DOM, set it to `display: block;`. [About the Display Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Of course, if you plan on working with animations, I would use the `visibility` property instead. [About the Visibility Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp)

Another solution is to simply wipe the element off by setting both the width and height to 0 when not being used. Remove the attribute width and height and apply it to the style.

```
style={
  { 
    width: index !== indexOfDiagnosis ? "0px" : "500px",
    height: index !== indexOfDiagnosis ? "0px" : "200px" 
  }
}
```

Comment: You say that my {...} produces an HTML of `inline-block<whitespace>inline-block<whitespace><inline-block>...`, and that because of these <whitespaces> the line preserves the height?

Comment: Yes, in static HTML this fixes it. The same would apply to any JS library depending how the HTML is inserted by the library and user.

Comment: I did try the static HTML example yesterday and I didnt notice the same problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/image-taking-space-in-block-layout-dqv99?file=/index.html

Comment: If I compare the HTML in the devtools of this plain HTML example and the React's one I don't see any difference. The whitespace between <img> elements cannot be spotted in the devtools.

Comment: That is odd... I will take another look. Any reason why you cannot use `display: block;` though?

Comment: I think display:block; is fine. The solution I'm currently using is "display: flex" on the parent element, as I described in the question. Also I tried to output the `el.textContent` of the parent element. And in plain HTML example it outputs 4-5 newlines, versus in React example where it outputs an empty string. Which is the opposite of what I expected.

Comment: Last resort alternative is setting the `font-size` to `0`, which will remove all white space characters, including spaces. I would say last resort as it removes the cascading effect inherited by parent elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225638/discussion-between-croraf-and-matthew-r-dangle).

Answer (score 2):

Setting the height of an image to `0` isn't enough to 'hide' it from the DOM.

The most common way to hide an image is to use [`display: none`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/996633/how-to-create-a-hidden-img-in-javascript/996669).

```
style={{ display: index === indexOfDiagnosis ? "block" : "none" }}
```

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-currying-03duk?file=/src/App.tsx:825-891)

---

EDIT:
Since OP is looking for a solution without `display:none`, here an example using the provided `height: 0px` together with an `font-size: 0px` on the parent element to prevent any space between the blocks.

```
<div style={{ fontSize: "0px" }}>
```

[How do I remove the space between inline/inline-block elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements)

[Updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-thunder-h1ceb?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks. display: none doesn't fit me because of some other things.

Comment: @croraf Could you clarify why you can't use `display:none`? Maybe you could add it to the question for further readers.

Comment: It is not that relevant. I have a bigger tree, and when doing display: none to the ancestor of the images they don't get loaded over the network until shown.

Comment: @croraf, thats a shame ;) Please check my edit, an other option using `font-size: 0px` to prevent whitespaces, please check the linked post!

Comment: Thanks. font-size: 0 indeed solves the problem. Well done. I tried line-height: 0 but that didnt do it :| . Although it did reduce the height

Comment: @croraf Glad it worked, I guess you should pick the most suiting fix mentioned in the linked post for your problem. Please consider upvoting/accepting any answers that helped.